# exFAT auto mount user rw

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, exfat

I have formatted an internal drive as exFAT so it can be shared with Windows if necessary and mounted it from Disks, creating the following `fstab` entry:

```
LABEL=Media /mnt/Media auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Media 0 0
```

This auto mounts the drive and I can read the drive but every file shows as root-owned and if I create a file there or copy a file there it defaults to 'root' even though I am not using `sudo` or logged in as root which is confusing. I want it to be readable and writable to **one** user uid=1000. `fuse-exfat` and `exfat-utils` are installed. Can I not change permissions on exFAT or have a mounted it as root but have given myself access to it?

`ls -l` shows every file as `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root` or 777

Answer (score 0):

FAT/FAT32/exFAT filesystems do not support users per file as common Linux filesystems, AFAIK. So, `chown` and `chgrp` will not work. However you can specify a single user/group for all files during mount

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/media/ -o uid=1000,gid=1000
```

(here `/dev/sdc` is just an example)